# Why does this Thymeleaf block get evaluated?

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf

I have the following Thymeleaf block.  When the `thedoc.addendum` is null, I don't see the `thedoc.addendemTitle` or `thedoc.addendum` (correctly) but the checkbox in the `span:sec` block gets evaluated.

```
<div th:if="${thedoc.addendum != null}">
<dt th:text="${thedoc.addendumTitle}">ADDENDUM</dt>
<dd>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
    <span th:text="${thedoc.addendum}">Custom addendum here</span>
    </div>
    <span sec:authorize="hasAnyRole('ROLE_A','ROLE_B','ROLE_C','ROLE_D')">
    <!-- THIS GETS EVALUATED --->
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ackAddendum" id="ackAddendum"/>
            <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
            <span class="text-success">I agree</span>
        </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /END EVALUATED -->
    </span>
</dd>
</div>
```

I also tried adding a not null check to the `<span:sec>` tag and also adding a not null check to the `<div class="checkbox">` tag, but it still evaluates the checkbox.

If the `sec:authorize` tag takes precedence over the outer `th:if`, how would I prevent display of the checkbox when `thedoc.addendum` is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that `thedoc.addendumTitle` is not empty? Can you add `<div th:text="${thedoc.addendum}"></div><div th:text="${thedoc.addendumTitle}"></div>` and look what the output is? I guess `thedoc.addendum` is never null it's only an empty-string. So you should use `#strings.isEmpty()`.

Otherwise you can use the following

```
<div th:if="${thedoc.addendum != null}">
<dt th:text="${thedoc.addendumTitle}">ADDENDUM</dt>
<dd>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
    <span th:text="${thedoc.addendum}">Custom addendum here</span>
    </div>
    <span sec:authorize="hasAnyRole('ROLE_A','ROLE_B','ROLE_C','ROLE_D')">
    <!-- THIS GETS EVALUATED --->
    <th:block th:if="${thedoc.addendum != null}">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ackAddendum" id="ackAddendum"/>
            <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
            <span class="text-success">I agree</span>
        </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    </th:block>
    <!-- /END EVALUATED -->
    </span>
</dd>
</div>
```

but it's only a workaround. If this work you should create a ticket for this.

Comment: Are you sure that `thedoc.addendumTitle` is not empty? Can you add `<div th:text="${thedoc.addendum}"></div><div th:text="${thedoc.addendumTitle}"></div>` and look what the output is? I guess thedoc.addendum is never null it's only an empty-string.

Comment: Foolish mistake.  After using !#strings.isEmpty(), this worked as expected.  Issue closed.